# How to register DLL in the GAC?

Tags: windows-installer, gac, esri-arc-engine

I am trying to install a C# WPF with a WindowsFormsHost which loads ESRI's ArcEngine.

The MSI installer gives this error:

```
Unable to install.  The app requires assembly ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework Version 
10.0.0.0 to be installed in the GAC first
```

I already installed the ESRI ArcEngine Runtime 10 which is supposed to handle this sort of thing, but I guess it's not perfect.

On the target machine the file framework.dll is in the folder:  `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet`, but it's not in `c:\windows\assembly`.

I right clicked on the assembly then clicked register to register but that didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two methods.

1. Using the utility gacutil -i

   `gactutil -i c:\foldername\assemblyname.dll`
2. The second method is you can drag the `.dll` file from the bin folder of the assembly and drop it into the folder `C:\%systemroot%\Assembly`

Comment: Whoa, is that all that's necessary these days? No command line?

Comment: "these days" was poorly put.  That's what *used* to work.  No more for the .NET 4.0 GAC.  Which might also explain the OP's problem.  Also, gacutil.exe is an SDK tool, not available on the target machine.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at ArcGIS 10 yet but I know previous versions of ArcGIS behaved that if you installed ArcGIS before you installed .NET it wouldn't install the feature that installed the DLL's to the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SDK installed, you can use the gacutil command:

```
path "%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322";%Path%
gacutil /i "%ProgramFiles%\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet\framework.dll"
```

Note that you have to be an Administrator to alter the Global Assembly Cache.